# What does "build" and "source" link do in "/lib/modules/<kernel-version>"

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module

I am compiling and installing the linux kernel. When I do `make modules_install`, I realize it has two links under the modules directory: `build` linked to where I output the compile things and `source` linked to where the kernel source is.

I'd like to know what are the two links doing? I copy the modules to another computer where does not have the directories `build` and `source` linked to. It works fine. Can I just remove these two links?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those symbolic links are relevant only as far as you compile 3rd party kernel drivers - typically make scripts rely on paths like `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build`.

If you don't intend to do this, they can be safely removed.